# Insert Multiple rows in a table using MVC Razor Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a scenario where in I need to store multiple rows in a single table.Let me explain it in detail.

I have a **table** `Price` which has **4 columns**, `ID, ModelID, AppSettingID,Amount`.

I am looking for inserting multiple values to the table where

1. ID would be the Primary Key.
2. ModelID would be same for all the rows.
3. AppSettingID and Amount will be different for all the rows and would be based on the selection user does on the view.

I have bound the AppSettingID to different combo boxes on the view as I have it categorized in the database.

This is what I am doing right now.

**View:**

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelID, "Model")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ModelID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppsettingID, "Mobile Condition")
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Mobile Condition", new       SelectList(ViewBag.ConditionID, "Text", "Value"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AppsettingID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppsettingID, "Tennure")
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Tennure", new SelectList(ViewBag.AppsettingID, "TexT", "Value"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AppsettingID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //ViewBag.AppsettingID = db.Appsettings.Select(r => r.ID).Distinct();
        ViewBag.ModelID = new SelectList(db.Models, "ID", "Name");
        //ViewBag.Tennure = db.Appsettings.Select(s => s.Type == "Tennure").Distinct();

        IQueryable<Appsetting>TennureIDs = db.Appsettings.Where(s => s.Type == "Tennure").Distinct();
        IQueryable<Appsetting> Conditions = db.Appsettings.Where(s => s.Type == "Mobile Condition").Distinct();

        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var t in TennureIDs)
        {
            SelectListItem s = new SelectListItem();
            s.Text = t.ID.ToString();
            s.Value = t.Value.ToString();
            items.Add(s);
        }
        ViewBag.AppsettingID = items;

        List<SelectListItem> conds = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var t in Conditions)
        {
            SelectListItem s = new SelectListItem();
            s.Text = t.ID.ToString();
            s.Value = t.Value.ToString();
            conds.Add(s);
        }

        ViewBag.ConditionID = conds;

        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Price/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Price price, FormCollection form)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int test = Convert.ToInt16(form["Mobile Condition"]);
            price.AppsettingID = test;
            db.Prices.Add(price);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //ViewBag.AppsettingID = new SelectList(db.Appsettings, "ID", "Type", price.AppsettingID);
        //ViewBag.ModelID = new SelectList(db.Models, "ID", "Name", price.ModelID);
        return View(price);
    }
```

Comment: Are you need to save the table rows which is in the razor to database?

Comment: @Golda, Yes from controller to Database.

Comment: How will you add a new rows to the model?

Comment: Please read this [interesting post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/editing-multiple-records-using-model-binding-in-mvc/)

Answer (score 4):

I hope this solution will help you

The following is a razor page, here I have displayed the model in table format

```
@model List<MyModel>

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Model ID
            </th>
            <th>
                App Setting ID
            </th>          
            <th>
                Amount
            </th>            
        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model[i].ModelID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model[i].AppsettingID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model[i].Amount)
                </td>
            </tr>                    
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

When user clicks the submit button, it will pass the model to the controller

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(List<MyModel> m)
    {
        // Do Coding
        return View("Create", m);
    }
```